# Intersection of two chords

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

Let AB and CD be two intersecting chords of a circle. How can I find the coordinates of the intersection point knowing only the euclidean coordinates of the endpoints A,B,C,D and the circle center point?

This can of course be solved with a segment-segment intersection algorithm (thanks for marking this question as duplicate, everyone), but I am asking if there is a simpler or more efficient algorithm that exploits the fact that the two line segments are chords of the same circle.

Comment: Draw $AB$ and $CD$, what are you asking?

Comment: What do you know about the endpoints, exactly? What do you mean by "find" the intersection point?

Comment: The points don't even have to be on a circle for you to find the intersection of two line segments.

Comment: @Sambo I know their euclidean coordinates. I know the circle center coordinates, too. I added this clarification to the question.

Comment: @user11171 Then the easiest thing to do would be to compute the equations of the lines which these segments are part of, and then compute their intersection in the usual way.

Comment: @amd the question asks if there is a different solution.

Comment: @Sambo I'd like something that runs faster for this special case. I was hoping there is a faster/simpler solution for chords.

Comment: Seems unlikely. You can compute this intersection with three cross products, two divisions, and a range check on the distance from the center. You might be able to do something with the arc angles, but nothing that doesn’t involve evaluating inverse trig functions immediately comes to mind.